# How to fix the background in the app when scaling the window, sfml

Tags: c++, sfml

Help with sfml, it is necessary to make so that the background application when scaling is not changed,

```
int main()
{
    ....
    View view;
    view.reset(FloatRect(0, 0, 1200, 700));
    float zoom = 1.0f;

    while (window.isOpen())
    {   
        ProcessEvents(window, clickState, zoom, view);
        ...
        window.setView(view);
        window.draw(bg);
        window.draw(vecBody.at(0).sprite);
        window.draw(text);  
    }
}
```

Without zoom
[image]

With zoom
[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you scale the view in or out, you need to adapt the background sprite to scale out or in (i.e. the inverse operation you applied on the view).

Have a look at [sf::Sprite::setScale](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.4.0/classsf_1_1Transformable.php#a4c48a87f1626047e448f9c1a68ff167e).